# How do I add to a GLib.List from different Thread in Vala

Tags: multithreading, glib, vala

I have a GLib.List to which I want to add elements.
I want to add those elements concurrently using multiple GLib.Threads

I'm trying to synchronize access to the list using a GLib.Mutex. Synchronization seems to work but no elements are added.

```
public static void main() {
    var list = new GLib.List<string>();
    var mutex = GLib.Mutex();

    var workerA = new Worker("A", list, mutex);
    var workerB = new Worker("B", list, mutex);
    var workerC = new Worker("C", list, mutex);

    GLib.Thread<void*> tA = new GLib.Thread<void*>("WorkerThread", workerA.run);
    GLib.Thread<void*> tB = new GLib.Thread<void*>("WorkerThread", workerB.run);
    GLib.Thread<void*> tC = new GLib.Thread<void*>("WorkerThread", workerC.run);

    tA.join();
    tB.join();
    tC.join();

    stdout.printf("List:\n");
    foreach (string str in list) {
        stdout.printf(" - %s\n", str);
    }
}

class Worker : GLib.Object {
    private string name;
    private weak GLib.List<string> list;
    private weak GLib.Mutex mutex;

    public Worker(string name, GLib.List<string> list, GLib.Mutex mutex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.list = list;
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void* run() {
        mutex.lock();
        list.append(name);
        mutex.unlock();

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I look at the synchronization part it seems to work right (even with many more Threads), but no elements get added to the list!

Output:

> List:

Can somebody please tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *apmasell* pointing out the thing not working is actually `GLib.List` I took a look at the [C source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/glist.c#n252).

He's right: The `append` method modifies the pointer - **but only** (!) if the `GLib.List` is empty!
So Apart from making the list a global variable or using another list implementation I think the best work workaround is to simply add one element before passing the list to a thread.
After all threads are done you can simply remove the element again.

Comment: Calling append is an O(N) operation.  It would be much better to call prepend (which is O(1)), then reverse the list when you're done.  Of course this messes up the hack you describe above—maybe you should just use a GLib.Sequence or GLib.Tree instead, which don't have the weird semantics and are both O(log N) for insertion.

Answer (score 1):

`GLib.List` is a little weird. The `append` method actually modifies the pointer `list`, not the thing it is pointing to. If you want this to work you need to either:

1. Put the list in a shared place (*e.g.*, make it a field of a class that all the threads share or a global variable).
2. Use `Gee.List` from the libgee package instead. In general, the data structures in libgee are much easier to use in Vala than their counter parts in glib.